# Hide selected option in next select box in select2 jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I stuck in this issue which is when a user selects an option from one select box the option should be hidden for the other select boxes. When a selected option changes the previously selected option should become available again to the other select boxes.

**The problem with my current code:**

My code is working when the select box is normal option, if I change to select2 it will not function. Anyone know how to do it if the select box is select2 :(?

```
Code: http://jsfiddle.net/t8170aqg/1/
```

Comment: The select 2 plugin has methods for modifying options. Use the plugin API. Note also that hide/show of `<option>` elements  is not supported cross browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues in your code

1. You are using `val` in option which is not correct your should use `value`
2. Also you not matching with val() of the selected option in the previous select you are mat aching the text which will be always different.

**Edit:** You have to use `.each` to set `attr` disabled for other options.

**Working Fiddle Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/bqzt1rf9/

Run snippet below to see it working.

**Using disabled attr on option**

```js
$(".s").select2()

$('.s').change(function() {
  let value = $(this).val()
  $(this).siblings('.s').children('option').attr('disabled', false)

  $('.s').each(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.s').children('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').attr('disabled', 'disabled')

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="datas_0 s">
  <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
  <option value="1">lim</option>
  <option value="2">tan</option>
  <option value="3">alax</option>
  <option value="4">king</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select class="datas_1 s">
  <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
  <option value="1">lim</option>
  <option value="2">tan</option>
  <option value="3">alex</option>
  <option value="4">king</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select class="datas_2 s">
  <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
  <option value="1">lim</option>
  <option value="2">tan</option>
  <option value="3">alex</option>
  <option value="4">king</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hide/show does not work in all browsers for `<option>`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks ;) yes i am aware. Hence why i suggested disabled `attr` or `remove` instead of `hide` or `show`

Comment: Hi @AlwaysHelping, seem like when a selected option changes the previously selected option no available.

Comment: For example, when first select box I select *lim* then the second select box will no have *lim* selection but when the first selectbox change to *tan*, then the *tan* option should able to select at other select box.

Comment: @MMMM Glad that i helped you. Cheers.